# Rails - Linking stylesheet and javascript in layout causes syntax error - "Missing ///"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

I came into work today to find that my project is throwing a syntax error for some reason, and I can't find a single thing about this error.

When using the `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_include_tag` helpers, I receive `SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: missing ///`.

Some things I have noted are:

1. If the links dont lead to a valid file, it compiles just fine.
2. Even if the files are empty the error is still thrown so the syntax error is definitely in the erb, even though I havent changed my `application.html.erb` since adding the link for the fonts.

**EDIT**:

3. After rewriting the layout in haml, the error persists, so I suspect it is not in the erb but in the ruby functions for linking, although I don't know what could have changed.
4. I just noticed the "ExecJs::RuntimeError", which is interesting because I commented out the javascript link so i could deal with one at a time.

Any help is appreciated. I feel like I'm missing somethinng very simple here, but i cant find it for the life of me.

If you want to see any of my code let me know, I wasnt sure what would be relevant other than this error page:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** 
Here's my "appllication.html.erb":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>{Site Name}</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300|Raleway|Tangerine:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>
    <%#<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your application.erb?

Comment: Yea, sorry, I just figured the 2 relevant tags were in the the error page output.

Comment: I've had similar errors before and in the past it's been a compilation error somewhere in the javascript stack rather than in the erb or haml.

Comment: @dstarh Thanks, I think I might know what the problem is now, I suppose I was too quick to dismiss javascript as the culprit. I didn't realize rails compiled the code even if it was never required.

Comment: I had same problem with Rails 5.1 sprockets 4. For me problem was naming issue. activeadmin.js instead of activeadmin.js.coffee solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by a compilation error somewhere in the rails asset pipeline. This specific instance was caused by a rogue TypeScript file in `app/assets/javascripts` after I had removed `typescript-rails` from my Gemfile.

Thanks to @dstarh I was able to find the error.

I'll leave this here since I couldn't find any information on this error anywhere. Hopefully it can help someone else.